# Using Transactions but still getting same objects from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase document "coupon" that has 2 fields inside: an array of strings and an integer as seen below

[image: Coupon Firebase Document]

Currently if a user clicks on a button to get a coupon, it will remove the 0 index at Firebase and show that removed array as coupon code in a Text widget, but if two or more users click on the button at the same time they all get the same string from the array.

This is my button on click code currently:

```
try {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .runTransaction((transaction) async {

    DocumentReference
        couponCollectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('coupons')
            .doc(widget.couponNumber);

    DocumentReference userCollectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(getUserID());
            
    setState(() {
      couponTitle = couponCode[0];
      couponBlur = 0.0;
      isButtonWorking = false;
    });

    transaction
        .update(couponCollectionReference, {
      'coupon_code': FieldValue.arrayRemove(
          [couponCode[0]]),
    });

    transaction
        .update(couponCollectionReference, {
      'coupons_available':
          FieldValue.increment(-1),
    });

    transaction
        .update(userCollectionReference, {
      'current_points':
          FieldValue.increment(-100),
    });

    await screenshotController
        .capture(
            pixelRatio: 2,
            delay: Duration(milliseconds: 20))
        .then((capturedImage) async {
      ShowCapturedWidget(
          context, capturedImage!);
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
  });
} catch (e)
```

Are transactions the way to go and I'm just not implementing them right or am I using a totally wrong approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `coupon` document to be considered part of the transaction, you have to read it from the database through the `transaction` object (and use the value of `coupons` from there).

In your code that'd be something like this:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .runTransaction((transaction) async {

  DocumentReference
      couponCollectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('coupons')
          .doc(widget.couponNumber);

  DocumentSnapshot couponDoc = await transaction.get(couponCollectionReference); // 

  couponCode = (couponDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['coupons'];
  ...
```

Comment: If I add the last line in your code it asks for a null check and if I implement one it throws **"The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'"**
If I change the **DocumentSnapshot** to **DocumentSnapshot<dynamic>** it throws the next:
`NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0)`

Comment: That wasn't the crux of my answer, so there could definitely be minor mistakes in that line. I updated it now based on https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read

Comment: That did the job, thank you so much!

Comment: Hello Frank, I just now noticed that the solution works on a android simulator and a real device but if using two real devices they both get the same string again ? Any thoughts ?

Comment: There is no difference between how the SDKs implement transactions, and there also shouldn't be any difference between the emulated database and the real one. Given that the initial issue was resolved by reading the document inside the transaction scope, it might be worth opening a new question and adding some logging information about what values each of the devices is reading inside the transaction, what it's writing, and  what you get in the `finally` when the transaction completes.