# Using Transactions but getting same objects from Firebase if two real devices used

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firebase document "coupon" as seen below

Currently if a user clicks on a button to get a coupon, it will remove the 0 index at Firebase and show that removed array as coupon code in a Text widget, but if two or more users click on the button at the same time they all get the same string from the array.

[image]

Below is the button onTap code that happens only when **coupons_available** is greater than 1

```
try {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .runTransaction((transaction) async {
    DocumentReference
        couponCollectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('coupons')
            .doc(widget.couponNumber);

    DocumentReference userCollectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(getUserID());

    DocumentSnapshot couponDoc =
        await transaction
            .get(couponCollectionReference);

    couponCode = (couponDoc.data() as Map<
        String, dynamic>)['coupon_code'];

    transaction
        .update(couponCollectionReference, {
      'coupon_code': FieldValue.arrayRemove(
          [couponCode[0]]),
    });

    transaction
        .update(couponCollectionReference, {
      'coupons_available':
          FieldValue.increment(-1),
    });

    transaction
        .update(userCollectionReference, {
      'current_points':
          FieldValue.increment(-100),
    });
  }).whenComplete(() async {
    setState(() {
      couponTitle = couponCode[0];
      couponBlur = 0.0;
      isButtonWorking = false;
      isButtonLoading = false;
    });
    await screenshotController
        .capture(
            pixelRatio: 2,
            delay: Duration(milliseconds: 500))
        .then((capturedImage) async {
      ShowCapturedWidget(
          context, capturedImage!);
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print(onError);
    });
  });
} catch (e) {
```

Currently this works great when trying it on an android emulator and a real device, but when using two real devices and clicking the button at the same time they still get the same string, what can be done ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the same string"?  Please edit the question to explain in more detail the specific behavior your observe and how that's different than what you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Question should be edited now, let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: Your code looks for "coupon_codes" but the field is actually called "coupon_code".

Comment: @DougStevenson That field in Firebase has been renamed properly, as I said everything works great if I try it on android emulator and a real device, clicking the button at the same time, but if using both real devices then clicking the button at the same time gets same strings

Comment: As I said in my last [comment on the previous question about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70580501/using-transactions-but-still-getting-same-objects-from-firebase/70581084?noredirect=1#comment124803409_70581084), you should include some more logging information here about the values you're getting from the database, the values you're writing back in response, and what you get in the `finally` when the transaction completes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for your comment, nothing is being written in the database, maybe I need to read the **current_coupons** integer from that document as well. Only the string is getting read and removed from the array. Let me know what you need and I will provide it